# How to use SassDoc as parser for single file without generating full documentation files

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

Question relates to http://sassdoc.com package

I would like to parse each *.scss file in ./source folder, but instead of generating sassdoc folder i would like to create partial-html for each parsed file. For example:

parse: variables.scss and receive variables.html, without page header, sidebar - pure content, even without html and body tags.

My current code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sassdoc = require('sassdoc');

var paths = {
  scss: [
    'source/**/*.scss'
  ]
};

gulp.task('sassdoc', function () {
  console.log("sassdoc task finished");
  return gulp.src(paths.scss)
    .pipe(sassdoc());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible with SassDoc' default theme. So you'd need to build your own theme to acheive this. 
http://sassdoc.com/using-your-own-theme

Each item is given a `file` key in resulting data, so I would leverage that and do some merging.

That could potentially end up in a `sassdoc-extra` custom filter.
http://sassdoc.com/extra-tools

EDIT:
Actually your question is quite misleanding, you want a `variable.html` file but with no `html` ...

If all that you want is the raw JSON data from SassDoc, without any kind of theme processing, then the [`parse` method](http://sassdoc.com/node/#using-raw-data) is what you're looking for.

But again, unless you call SassDoc on each file separately, you'll get all files together, meaning post data processing to split them, that's why a custom theme (even with no html output) is the way to go.